# Hide controller name from the url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, routes

i want to hide the controller name from the url and to do that i am doing

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "AccountRoute",
        "{action}",
        new { controller = "Account", action = "Index" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
           "Default", // Route name
           "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
           new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }// Parameter defaults
       );

    }
```

but when I try to go

localhost:1234/Settings - dont work.

but

localhost:1234/Account/Settings -works..

There are many questions about this and all of them suggest what I already have above.
where am I doing wrong?? or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `AccountRoute` below the `Default` route.  Just keep in mind that creating routes like this can lead to unintended consequences.

Comment: Having actions with the same name in both your Account controller and some other controller.  Just have to be vigilant with the naming and realizing which route will pick up the request.  Important when having multiple people work on a project.

Comment: ok..i got that now..by the way moving the 'accountroute' under the'default', didnt solve it.

Comment: @GvM what if we user **area** with having default route to Account controoller

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding an optional parameter to the AccountRoute. Be careful that your actions do not have the same name as a controller or the routing won't work correctly.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AccountRoute",
    "{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: You might have to check that Account controller is in the correct / expected namespace.